# MySQL Update Attribute of Table1 with Attribute of Table2

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

While using following SQL Statement:

```
UPDATE nsuppliercomponent
INNER JOIN nsuppliercomponent ON supplier.supplierName = nsuppliercomponent.supplierId
SET nsuppliercomponent.supplierId = supplier.supplierId WHERE
nsuppliercomponent.supplierId = supplier.supplierName;
```

I get following error message:

```
Error

SQL query:

UPDATE nsuppliercomponent
INNER JOIN nsuppliercomponent ON supplier.supplierName = nsuppliercomponent.supplierId
SET nsuppliercomponent.supplierId = supplier.supplierId WHERE
nsuppliercomponent.supplierId = supplier.supplierName

MySQL said: Documentation
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'nsuppliercomponent'
```

I have 2 Tables in TableA i store all the numbers from the suppliers in TableB i store the Suppliers themselves. I would like to use ForeignKeys later on why i need to change the supplierID from TableA where everything at the moment is stored as a String containing the Name to a INT with the right supplier ID

Tables as follows:
TableA:
[image]

TableB:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple typo I think, you joined the same table twice instead of the `supplier` table:

```
UPDATE nsuppliercomponent
INNER JOIN supplier ON supplier.supplierName = nsuppliercomponent.supplierId
....
```